# How to use this codes? I want to add moving marker like a car in my map

Tags: android, eclipse

Just want to know how to use this codes? 'cause everytime I paste this codes in my java, there is nothing happen... Please help me. I want to add moving marker inside map for my app. 
 thanks for advance :)

```
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    try {
        if(map == null) {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }

        if(map != null) {

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

 public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
            final boolean hideMarker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = map.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 500;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarker) {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

.......

Comment: developer.android.com.  Start here.  You can't build apps with copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple application to understand how to use the code. But in this case, I do not see the use of the method animateMarker. You need someone who would cause it (eg, button).